# How add to crontab sphinx index?

Tags: centos, cron, server

I added an line to crontab file:

```
*/5 * * * * indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate
```

But it does not work!

İ tried:

```
$crontab -l
0 * * * * /etc/sphinx/indexer.sh
*/5 * * * * /etc/sphinx/searchd.sh
```

**indexer.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate > /dev/null
```

**searchd.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

runing=`ps ax | grep "searchd" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`

if [ $runing -eq 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If I could comment, this would be a comment ...

based on the information you provided it is hard to guess what is going wrong. My first guess would be a permission problem. Did you run

```
crontab -e
```

with a user with sufficient permissions to run the indexer script? Does the script run when triggered manually?